# JQquery UI this._addClass is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Использую на странице JQuery UI slider ( https://jqueryui.com/slider/ ), при загрузке страницы с Safari на MacOS возникает ошибка

[image: ошибка]

В Хроме, Хромиуме, Опере, Мозилле, IE и в Safari для Windows подобной проблемы не возникает.

Comment: перед этой ошибкой есть еще какая-нибудь? На странице с примером все работает?

Comment: элемент который вы выбираете не является элементом jQuery, а значит и метода `_addClass` у него нет. Выбранный вами элемент чистый элемент DOM

Answer (score 1):

Теряется контекст. Соответственно и методы.
У меня была такая проблема из за того что запускал в конструкции

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {})
```

так как было лень разбираться просто вынес код за его пределы